# How can I use Apache Airflow to build dynamic DAGs using the GUI?

Tags: airflow, workflow, pipeline

I am looking for a technique that I can build and control DAG's tasks from GUI, to allow the end user to create its own DAGs or control some tasks inside a DAG.

I've tried Apache Airflow, It's really nice, but I couldn't create a custom DAG from the GUI that includes predefined tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Airflow DAG is defined through Python code. So you can create your own DSL that is generated from the GUI-designed DAG. Then you can write Python code that generates Airflow DAG from your DSL document.

Another option is to use [temporal.io](https://temporal.io/) open source orchestrator that allows you to write an interpreter for any custom DSL directly in a programming language of your choice without converting it to an intermediate representation.